# Ошибка в регулярном выражении, лишний обратный слэш

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте, товарищи!

Есть регулярка, исключающая вот этот набор символов: `*{}\/[]#@&<>`

Вот само выражение: `/^(?!.*\{\}\\/\[\]#@&<>$)(.*)$/`

Выдаёт ошибку: **Warning:** preg_match(): Unknown modifier '\' in **/path_to/index.php** on line **485**

Подскажите пожалуйста, где этот лишний обратный слэш.

Comment: замените ограничители шаблона, к примеру на тильды: `~^(?!.*\{\}\\/\[\]#@&<>$)(.*)$~`

Answer (score 0):

[image: Ругается на слеш по центру]

Советую сайт для проверки регулярных выражений https://regex101.com/

Comment: А бэкслэш-то всё-таки какой? :)

Comment: Который красном отмечен)

Comment: Но это же не бэкслэш и если его удалить, то будет пропускать вот этот символ «/»

Comment: Поробуй экранировать его
^(?!.*\{\}\\\/\[\]#@&<>$)(.*)$